# Edit todo from list in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I don't know why I can't make it work but I just want to edit the todo from the list and save it `onBlur` (when I press outside the box). I've made this work before but I think I got brain freeze or something. I deleted my attempts so the functions are empty now. Can someone nudge me in the right direction or just fill in the blanks? Thank you

UPDATE: so I want to press the todo that I've added to the list (the textinput) and then EDIT the already present todo, THEN save it to the list again!

```
      const TEST = () => {
    
        const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")
        const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([])
      
    
       const onChangeHandler = (text) =>{
            setTodo(text)
        }
    
        const saveTodo = () =>{
            setTodoList([...todoList , {title: todo, key:`${Math.random()}`}])
            setTodo("")
        }
    
    
       const onChangeTodo = () =>{
    
    //UPDATE HERE
       }
    
        const saveonChangeTodo = () =>{
    //SAVE HERE
    
        }
    
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: "beige", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", paddingTop: 300,}}>
                <TextInput
                placeholder="Write todo here"
                style={{backgroundColor:"white", padding: 20, width: 300,}}
                value={todo}
                onChangeText={text=>onChangeHandler(text)}
                onBlur={saveTodo}
                />
    
                <FlatList
                data={todoList}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return(<TextInput style={{borderColor: "black", borderWidth: 2, width: 200, padding: 20, margin: 10}}
                    value={item.title}
                    onChangeText={text=>onChangeTodo(text, item)}
                    onBlur={saveonChangeTodo}
                    /> 
                            
                               
                    )
                }}/>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working, please embed the error you get or tell us what is the current behavior

Comment: Not 100% certain, but could you try changing your setTodoList to: 

    `setTodoList(prev, [...prev, {title: todo, key:`${Math.random()}`}])`

I don't know if that makes a difference!!

Comment: Ah I think I was a bit unclear. I want to be able to press the todo (textinput) and then change the todo that is inside it (just edit it) then save it etc. That logic should be in onChangeToDo and saveonChangeTodo

Comment: I'll update the question so its a bit more clear!

Comment: Ok, write the code that you have to write `UPDATE HERE` and I will tell you if come across a problem

Comment: Yes thats the problem I don't understand how exactly to write it. Because I need to access that specific todo and update it - so I guess I need help with the logic of doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `onChangeTodo` as below. No need to have `saveonChangeTodo` as it is already supported by `onChangeTodo`.

```
const onChangeTodo = (text, item) => {
    setTodoList((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.key === item.key ? { ...todo, title: text } : todo
      )
    );
};
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-web-forked-jf55i?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Ollie, check this out !!